# How to add values in a range of cells if neighboring cell has a specific string value only those cell get added to the sum?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

If the category matches the categories string value, how do I add the amount next to the category to the Totals for the categories legend

So far I've tried using the SUMIF() function.

Comment: You shouldn't have problems using `SUMIF()` in Excel Table. For example: `SUMIF(Table1[Category],[@Categories],Table1[Amount])` would you share the function that is provoking `#SPILL!`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image: sample excel file]

Where the Excel table on the left is named as `Table3`. You get `#SPILL!` because you are using the formula like this:

```
=SUMIF(Table3[Category],[Categories],Table3[Amount])
```

You forgot to include `@` that means the category value of a given row. Using `[Categories]` will generate an array and it is not supported for Excel Tables so you get `#SPILL!`. Check the following information:

1. [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).
2. [#SPILL! error - Table formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-spill-error-table-formula-8bfa1758-1be4-42f4-a974-c4d4bc513d4b)

Answer (score 0):

Try `SUMIFS()`.

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Amount],Table1[Category],[@Category])
```

[image]